# R - selecting common elements from vectors

Tags: r

I've got data as below

```
vec1 = c("text1", "text2", "text3")
vec2 = c("text2", "text3")
vec3 = c("text2", "text4")
```

I want to obtain common elements in all three vectors and subgroups of two of them.

vec1_2_3 : "text2"

vec1_2   : "text2" "text3"

vec1_3   : "text2"

vec2_3   : "text2"

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R option (assuming all those variables are named in the format `vecXXX`)

```
vec <- mget(ls(pattern = "vec\\d+"))
unlist(
  sapply(
    2:length(vec),
    function(k) {
      setNames(
        combn(vec, k, FUN = function(x) Reduce(intersect, x), simplify = FALSE),
        combn(names(vec), k, toString)
      )
    }
  ),
  recursive = FALSE
)
```

which gives

```
$`vec1, vec2`
[1] "text2" "text3"

$`vec1, vec3`
[1] "text2"

$`vec2, vec3`
[1] "text2"

$`vec1, vec2, vec3`
[1] "text2"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a function called `intersect` that finds the common values from vectors, here is an example:

```r
vec1 = c("text1", "text2", "text3")
vec2 = c("text2", "text3")
vec3 = c("text2", "text4")

library(dplyr)
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

# Since I think you can only have two vectors in an intersect here,
# youll need to have it like this:
intersect(vec1, intersect(vec2, vec3))
#> [1] "text2"
intersect(vec2, vec3)
#> [1] "text2"
intersect(vec1, vec2)
#> [1] "text2" "text3"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Hope this helped!